# IPN status retrying

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

As I have implemented IPN in my page, in IPN history status of transaction shown as "Retrying" and after some time its failed.

Where should be lack?

Note: My IPN url is live and it is not on localhost. getting PDT response successfully

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PDT and IPN together. Completely disable PDT and try again.